# NotFoundError when import tfq

Tags: tfq

I tried to import tfq, but couldn't and got an error like this:
NotFoundError: /home/ugisugih/anaconda3/envs/tfq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_quantum/core/ops/_tfq_simulate_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringERKNS_15OpKernelContextEb

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running into issues with the way you installed TensorFlow Quantum.

You can have different issues dependent on whether you used for example pip or conda. This discussion may be of some help: https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/180

If you want effective help in this forum you will need to post the steps you used to install TensorFlow Quantum so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I've install python Python 3.9.18, cirq 0.14.1, tensorflow 2.14.0, tensorflow-quantum 0.7.1.   I followed the step michael's solution at https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/180, but still NotFoundError.